# How to access public Property MyProperty of class A in class C

Tags: c#

I have following code:

```
public class A
{
   public int MyProperty {get; set;}
}

public class B
{
   A myInstance = new A();
   myInstance.MyProperty = 10;
}

public class C
{
   public void InvokeA()
   {
        //How to access MyPropery here?
        BInstance = new B();
        Console.WriteLine(B.myInstance.MyProperty.ToString()); 
   }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to access MyProperty as written above. Inheritance is not an option since my class C is already inherited from some base class. A way without declaring any of the given classes as static would be nice!

Comment: `B` has to be an *instance* if you want to access its members.

Comment: For the access you describe, the properties would have to be declared as `static` - is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I guess @Codor was confused because I used "MyProperty" like a static property before the edit. Sorry!

Comment: @Orzowei pls reopen your question I will add my answer

Comment: @Alexandr Thanks for your effort! I'm new to stackoverlow.com and don't know how to reopen it. I edited my question but it's still on hold.

Comment: the syntax of class B is not correct. myInstance is a private property of class B and you can neither access it nor initialize MyProperty without a constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider following classes:

```
public class A
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public A GetAInstance()
    {
        A myInstance = new A();
        myInstance.MyProperty = 10;

        return myInstance;
    }
}

public class C
{
    private B BInstance;

    public void InvokeA()
    {
        BInstance = new B();

        Console.WriteLine(BInstance.GetAInstance());
    }
}
```

and then you will create your C instance in Main:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        C cInstance = new C();
        cInstance.InvokeA();
    }
```

Comment: @Orzowei, does that answer your question?

Comment: had no chance to try it yet, I'll let you know! Thanks so far!

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish your goal, you need to expose `B.MyInstance` as a property of the `B` class, just like you exposed `A.MyProperty` as a property of the `A` class.

Edit: Per the comments of others regarding use of the `static` keyword, here's what you *might* want your code to look like:

```
public class A
{
   public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public static class B
{
   static B()
   {
       MyInstance = new A();
       MyInstance.MyProperty = 10;
   }

   public static A MyInstance { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
   // not sure what your intention is here
   public C()
   {
       System.Console.WriteLine(B.MyInstance.MyProperty.ToString()); // "10\n"
   }
}
```

Comment: However [`beware.Of().Train.Wrecks()`](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2011/12/30/how-many-train-wrecks-are-lurking-in-your-code)

Comment: Downvoting something without an explanation is one of the least constructive things you can do on StackOverflow. I'm happy to accept the fact that this isn't a good answer, but at least please let me know why you think that! We're all here to learn something!

Comment: @MatthewWatson - Ahahaha! Nah, I wasn't. Anyways, your comment relates to the code in the OP's question, not so much my response to said question.

Comment: Indeed; your answer is correct as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can inherits classes from A to B something like this:

```
public class A
{
   public int MyProperty {get; set;}
}

public class B : A
{
    public B()
        : A() 
    {
        MyProperty = 1;
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
(new B()).MyProperty
```

Or use Singleton approach to resolve:

```
public class B
{
    private static _a;

    public class A
    {
        public int MyProperty {get; set;}
    }

    public static A AA {
        if (_a == null) {
            _a = new A();
        }

        return _a;
    }  
}
```

This implmentation will return

```
B.A.MyProperty.ToString();
```

Comment: Inheritance cant workt for me because my class is already inherited. I'm gonna try the other solution! Thanks!

Comment: @Orzowei - if you found my answer helpful, I'd appreciate it if you could mark it as such. If it doesn't get you where you're trying to go, please let me know what's missing.

Comment: @Orzowei - glad to hear that it helped! Sounds like you're just getting started with C# - I find it to be one of the most enjoyable programming languages to work in. Have fun!